# how to filter firestore data on client side in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I get data from firestore like this

```
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]);

  const getProjects = (sortBy = "NAME_ASC") => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("projects")
      .orderBy(SORT_OPTIONS[sortBy].column, SORT_OPTIONS[sortBy].direction)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        const newProjects = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }));

        setProjects(newProjects);
      });
    return () => unsubscribe();
  };
```

I have a from to apply a filter agains the `name` key ob the data object like this:

```
<form>
    <input
       type="text"
       value={filter}
       onChange={(e) => applyFilter(e.currentTarget.value)}
    />
</form>
```

and here is my filter function:

```
  const applyFilter = (filter) => {
    setFilter(filter);
    const filtered = projects.filter((e) => e.name.includes(filter));
    setProjects(filtered);
  };
```

The filter works fine, but once my data is filtered, I can't undo the filter or filter something complely different because with `setProjects(filtered)` I overwrite the entire data fetched from firestore.

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: you should be doing that on the view otherwise you need a copy which you ll always filter against

Comment: What means "on the view"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `setProjects` in your filter, its overwriting the data which is held within `projects`. This is obviously bad, as you are losing your list of data while you are filtering.

Its best to keep your original data, `projects` and then also keep state for filter results, `filteredProjects` and conditionally choose which to use as the data source, depending on if you have a filter.

```
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState([]); //Original data, dont mutate
  const [filteredProjects, setFilteredProjects] = useState([]); //holds filter results
  const [filter, setFilter] = useState(""); //filter string (not sure where you keep this)


  const getProjects = (sortBy = "NAME_ASC") => {
    const unsubscribe = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("projects")
      .orderBy(SORT_OPTIONS[sortBy].column, SORT_OPTIONS[sortBy].direction)
      .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
        const newProjects = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
          id: doc.id,
          ...doc.data(),
        }));

        setProjects(newProjects);
      });
    return () => unsubscribe();
  };
```

Your filter function will now update the `filteredProjects` state (so it does not overwrite your `projects` state

```
  const applyFilter = (filter) => {
    setFilter(filter);
    const filtered = projects.filter((e) => e.name.includes(filter));
    setFilteredProjects(filtered);
  };
```

now you can conditionally choose which set of data to provide to your view, depending if you have a filter value or not. I do not know what your return method looks like or where you are using it.. but here I have mocked a component called "ProjectsView" which displayed the projects based on the filter.

```
<form>
    <input
       type="text"
       value={filter}
       onChange={(e) => applyFilter(e.currentTarget.value)}
    />
</form>
<ProjectsView
   projectData={filter.length > 0 ? filteredProjects : projects} //choose the filteredProjects if there is a filter string length is greater than 0, otherwise the original list
/>
```